# Apollo Array of Custom Input types as Mutation argument throws "__typename": Unknown field error

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphene-python

I do not quite understand what the error even is to be able to tackle this problem. Checking server console also doesn't show any descriptive error. I have added all the necessary code that is related to this issue.

Here is the mutation:

```
mutation SaveTrials($event: ID!, $input: [ResultTrialsInputType!]!) {
    saveTrials(event: $event, results: $input) {
        results {
            id
            trials
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Graphene (Python) in backend but the types correspond to the following:

```
input ResultTrialsInputType {
    id: ID
    person: ID!
    trials: [String]
}
```

Here is the Python code if it matters:

```
class ResultTrialsInputType(graphene.InputObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID()
    person = graphene.ID(required=True)
    trials = graphene.List(graphene.String)
```

When I send data from the apollo using the mutation above, this is what is being sent to the API:

```
{
    "operationName": "SaveTrials",
    "variables": {
        "event": "207e9f27-be66-4564-9c28-ac92ec44235d",
        "input": [
            {
                "id": "8eb80b8b-c93a-44b1-9624-e75436c13780",
                "trials": [
                    "32.1",
                    "92.2",
                    "12.1",
                    "12.2",
                    "23.2",
                    ""
                ],
                "__typename": "ResultTrialsObjectType",
                "person": "a6f18ab5-df23-421e-b916-73e569bf73ad"
            }
        ]
    },
    "query": "mutation SaveTrials($event: ID!, $input: [ResultTrialsInputType!]!) {\n  saveTrials(event: $event, results: $input) {\n    results {\n      id\n      trials\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

Response for this query is an error about "__typename":

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Variable \"$input\" got invalid value [{\"__typename\": \"ResultTrialsObjectType\", \"person\": \"a6f18ab5-df23-421e-b916-73e569bf73ad\", \"id\": \"8eb80b8b-c93a-44b1-9624-e75436c13780\", \"trials\": [\"32.1\", \"92.2\", \"12.1\", \"12.2\", \"23.2\", \"\"]}].\nIn element #0: In field \"__typename\": Unknown field.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 34
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In anywhere else in my application where an input argument is not array of custom objects as expected. What is the deal here? Am I setting my input arguments in the wrong way? Or am I missing something here?

I tried to add `__typename` manually to the input type; however, nothing happened.

Thanks!

EDIT: Now that I am checking this out, for some reason `__typename` is displayed as `ResultTrialsObjectType` but it should be `ResultTrialsInputType`. How is this value being generated? Does Apollo generate it or does server generate it and Apollo fetches it?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema specifies that `ResultTrialsInputType` has three fields: `id`, `person`, `trials`. `__typename` is a special [meta-field](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Type-Name-Introspection) that signifies the type of an object -- it should not be added to the schema. In fact, any names that start with two underscores [are reserved](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Reserved-Names) and should not be used for field names.

As the error indicates, the issue is that `__typename` is not a field that's specified for `ResultTrialsInputType`, but you're sending it anyway.

Apollo will automatically attach `__typename` to any selection sets in your request (**not** inputs or variable values). So a query like this:

```
query {
  foo {
    bar
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
query {
  foo {
    bar
    __typename
  }
}
```

Apollo needs the `__typename` for every Object returned in your response in order to [effectively cache the response](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching). However, this means any time you are working with a `data` object returned by Apollo, it will have `__typename` properties throughout its structure.

What this boils down to is that, generally speaking, you cannot and should not make a query, mutate the response and then turn around and use that as an input to another query or mutation.

Comment: What should you do instead? if not that? `What this boils down to is that, generally speaking, you cannot and should not make a query, mutate the response and then turn around and use that as an input to another query or mutation.`